# Define words in a text by hovering over them

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, definition

I am trying to create a program for teaching English.
My aim is to take a text and have it so that students can read the text, and get the definition of individual words by hovering over any words that they don't understand.

Ideally I want this to link to Dictionary.com or something similar so that I do not have to input the definition for every individual word.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can use Javascript, CSS or HTML, but so far I haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using vanilla JS CSS and Axios for the request to a dictionary api.

Please note - this will get the first definition of the word only, this could be modified to show all definitions by looping through them with a simple for of loop.

```js
async function getDefinition(word) {
  let response = await axios.get(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${word}`, {
    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json"
    }
  });
  document.getElementById('def').innerHTML = response.data[0].meanings[0].definitions[0].definition;
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.myDIV:hover+.hide {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.3.4/axios.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDIV" id="hover" onMouseOver="getDefinition('discombobulated')">Discombobulated</div>
<div class="hide" id="def"></div>
```